# Template filter for custom taxonomy terms

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, filters, templates, hooks

I want to replace custom taxonomy term template with my custom template. Like using `add_filter('single_template','customFun');` replaces single custom post type template.

I have a custom taxonomy e.g `CustomCat` and there are terms e.g `hello cat`.

When I view hello-cat I want to have my custom template i.e all code in my plugin like [add_filter('single_template');](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this dynamic filter within the `get_query_template()` function:

```
    /**
     * Filter the path of the queried template by type.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$type`, refers to the filename -- minus the file
     * extension and any non-alphanumeric characters delimiting words -- of the file to load.
     * This hook also applies to various types of files loaded as part of the Template Hierarchy.
     *
     * Possible values for `$type` include: 'index', '404', 'archive', 'author', 'category', 'tag', 'taxonomy', 'date',
     * 'home', 'front_page', 'page', 'paged', 'search', 'single', 'singular', and 'attachment'.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param string $template Path to the template. See locate_template().
     */
    return apply_filters( "{$type}_template", $template );
```

where in your case the type is `taxonomy`.

You mentioned your own custom plugin. So if you want to override the template for your `hello-cat` term of your custom taxonomy, with a custom template within your plugin, then you can try the following within your root plugin file:

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', function( $template )
{
    $mytemplate = __DIR__ . '/templates/custom.php';

    if( is_tax( 'some-custom-tax-slug', 'hello-cat' ) && is_readable( $mytemplate ) )
        $template =  $mytemplate;

    return $template;
} );
```

where the custom template is placed within your custom plugin folder, like:

```
/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/templates/custom.php
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer :) but I am still in mid of your solution. Now     I am using add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'magicalendar_get_event_page' ); function magicalendar_get_event_page($content){ return $content } but I want to run it only when taxonomy is "wordpress"

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do this only from a plugin, but if modifying the theme is ok, then go with what Pieter Goosen suggests @BhuvneshGupta

Comment: [`is_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_taxonomy/) is depreciated, isn't it ;-)

Comment: ups, yes, I think I wanted to use is_tax() here, just writing from a sloppy memory, thanks ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Hahahaha, just wanted to get your memory jumpstarted. Seems like you are having a bad head day ;-) @birgire

Comment: this happens when there's no caffeine in the morning, but usually happens with caffeinie too, so I've no  excuse ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need any filter here or any custom template. Just create a `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term->slug}.php` template in your child theme (*or own theme*) where:

- `$taxonomy` is the name of your taxonomy
- `$term->slug` is the slug of the term.

WordPress will automatically use that template for the particular term when you visit that term's archive page